# How do I change the authentication of an existing ASP.NET application to integrate it with SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, integration, asp.net

I have a business portal configured using "Online SharePoint Service". Now I want to integrate our LMS (Leave Management System) with that portal. Below is little bit more information and difficulties in defining approach.

- Current LMS is developed in ASP.NET and hosted on local server.
- Current LMS have set of users which can use it by logging into application using Login functionality of site.
- Current LMS is accessed by the users, whose information are stored in Database. In other words, we are not using "Windows Authentication" for logging in to application.

I would like to know that, how can I develop the below mentioned, proposed functionality to integrate LMS with Online SharePoint Service.

- Integrate LMS with SharePoint portal. (Placing published code on same server or other dedicated .Net server)
- All the users logged into the SharePoint can directly access the LMS without asking for Login again. Existing users needs to be added in SharePoint portal and access application from there.
- Authentication of users using comparison in database should be removed and other approach like Windows Authentication or any other.
- Mechanism and changes in existing application to provide such functionality

Any kind of assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2007 ? This will make a lot of difference on the code, on the authentication and on the functionnalities...

Comment: Hi Sebastien. 

I am ready for any changes, but I don't find any concrete approach to do this. If you can help me out by providing some code or approach then you will be an angel for me.

We basically use SharePoint 2007.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to investigate building a custom Single Sign-On Provider. MSDN has an example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms566925(office.12).aspx

Comment: Hi

Thank you for the reply.

Is there any other approach then SSO.

Thanks.